# Can anyone help me explaining line 2 of this python program?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am doing leedcode problem and I found this solution online. I haven't understood line 2 `lookup = {x[0]: i for i, x in enumerate(pieces)}`. Can anyone tell me how is it working? Also it will be cool if you can help me understanding whole program.

```
def canFormArray( arr, pieces):
    
    lookup = {x[0]: i for i, x in enumerate(pieces)}
    
    i = 0
    while i < len(arr): 
        if arr[i] not in lookup:
            return False
        for c in pieces[lookup[arr[i]]]:
            if i == len(arr) or arr[i] != c:
                return False
            i += 1
    return True 

       
arr = [15,88]
pieces = [[88],[15]]
p = canFormArray(arr,pieces)
print(p)
```

Comment: Which specific part of it do you not understand?

Comment: @LeonardusChen How is it workin?  for c in pieces[lookup[arr[i]]]:

Comment: here https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Google ***list comprehension***.

`lookup = {x[0]: i for i, x in enumerate(pieces)}`

can be translated as

```
lookup = {} # init empty dict
for i, x in enumerate(pieces):
    lookup[x[0]] = i
```

Comment: You should be reading more tutorial about the data structure and the syntax in Python before moving on. This line assigns `i` to the key `x[0]` in `lookup`

Comment: ```lookup[x[0]]``` creates a new key for the dictionary @DiptinKharel

Comment: @coderoftheday and what about values? how they are created? when I print lookup, it shows me both value and key. How are these created?

Comment: ```i``` is the value, ```i``` takes a new value every iteration.